# Multicast group clients doesn't receive the message from server

Tags: java, udp, multicast

I created a chat application to sent messages to a multicast group conversation with multiple clients.

The message has to been send to the `MulticastServer` and sent to all client on Multicast Group. At this point, the message arrive at the server from client in perfect conditions.

But when i reply back to client (even a simple String), the message is sending only to the client that send the message and not for all users in the Multicast Group.

The StackTrace doesn't give me any error, but i still getting this issue.

I give you some of the important code. The following one refering the connection to multicast server. The `DEFAULT_ADRESS` is 224.0.0.3.

```
    socket = new MulticastSocket();
    address = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_ADRESS);
    socket.joinGroup(address);
```

The part of the code that send a message to MulticastServer:

```
String messtoSendServer = utilizadorOnline.getNome() + ":" + textfieldtocomunicateGroupe.getText();

        buf = messtoSendServer.getBytes();

        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, DEFAULT_PORT);

        try {
            // userOnline_Multicast.getSocketMulti().send(packet);
            socket.send(packet);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

The part of the code that receive the message from server:

```
  private void receberDadosServidor() throws IOException {



            try {

                DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                socket.receive(packet1);

                String received = new String(packet1.getData());

                textareatoGroupChat.setText(textareatoGroupChat.getText() + "\n" + received);

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                socket.close();
                socket.leaveGroup(address);
            }
```

This is the Server Side. First start the Thread:

```
 public void run(JTextArea txtArea) throws IOException {


       new MulticastServerThread(txtArea).start();
    }
```

And the Thread herself:

```
public class MulticastServerThread extends Thread {

    private final String DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP = "224.0.0.3";
    private final int DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT = 4446;
    private final int FIVE_SECONDS =5000;
    private DatagramPacket packet;
    private JTextArea textA;
    private boolean moreQuotes = true;
    private MulticastSocket socket = null;

    private InetAddress adresstoConnectMulticast = null;

    public MulticastServerThread(JTextArea txt) throws IOException {
        super("MulticastServerThread");
        this.textA = txt;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                socket = new MulticastSocket(DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT);
                adresstoConnectMulticast = InetAddress.getByName(DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP);

                socket.joinGroup(adresstoConnectMulticast);

                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, adresstoConnectMulticast, DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT); //usado para receber um datagram do socket, o array de bytes contem dados do cliente especifico

                socket.receive(packet);

                String mensagem = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

                textA.setText(textA.getText() + "\n\nServer Multicast Receive from User:" + mensagem +" on IP Multicast " +DEFAULT_MULTICASTIP +" | "+ DEFAULT_MULTICASTPORT);

                buf = mensagem.getBytes();
                InetAddress ed = packet.getAddress();
                int portad = packet.getPort();

//manda de volta para o cliente.
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ed, portad);
                socket.send(packet);

                try {

                    sleep((long) Math.random() * FIVE_SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MulticastServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                socket.close();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

```
socket = new MulticastSocket();
```

Your clients all need to be bound to the same port. Provide a fixed port number to the constructor. Otherwise you get a system-allocated port.

Second, your server replies to the source's IP address and port number. It should reply to the group IP address and the source's port number, or the fixed port number above, which should be the same.

Third, 224.0.0.3 is reserved. You can't use it.

And leave the server's socket open. Don't open and close it every time around the loop.

Comment: Thanks EJP, i had another problem. How  is the best way to client waits from a response by the server? My program at the moment i need to push the button many times in each client to see the message sended by a particular client.

Comment: It works now, i add a while loop in receving method!